# Scripts for finding the largest and smallest number in a data file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Suppose there is a data file `data.txt` which has the below content:

```
176.05 174.66 169.81 143.48 188.23 186.74 135.95 181.69 162.19 96.84 205.55
```

The output would be something like:

```
min: 96.84
max: 205.55
```

Any simple scripts can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU awk:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$1}END{asort(a);print "min: ",a[1],"\nmax: "a[NR]}' RS=' ' file
min:  96.84 
max: 205.55
```

If you don't:

```
awk '{x=$1>x?$1:x;m=$1<m?$1:m}END{print "min: ",m,"\nmax: ",x}' RS=' ' m=inf x=-m file
min:  96.84 
max:  205.55
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward awk solution

```
awk 'NR==1{max=min=$1;}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){max=max<$i?$i:max;min=min>$i?$i:min;}}END{print "max:",max,"\nmin:",min;}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWK script which does that. I removed the spaces to fit more on one line, you can space it out if you want.

```
awk '{min=$1;max=$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i>max)max=$i;if($i<min)min=$i}print "min:",min,", max:",max}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell by now, `awk` is a good tool for this job. Here's a variation that changes
the record separator to treat each number as a separate record in the input:

```
awk '{max=($1>max)?$1:max;
      min=($1<min)?$1:min;
     }
     END{printf "min: %s\nmax: %s\n",min,max}' \
   RS=" "  min=inf max=-inf file.txt
```